# Passing ACF map data to a twig loop in Timber theme

Tags: php, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

I inherited a site using a custom Timber theme and am very confused about how to translate solutions in regular PHP into Twig syntax. I need to display multiple markers on a Google map using a custom post type (venues). I have a working query to gather all published venues:

```
$venue_query = array(
    'post_type' => 'venue',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$context['venue'] = Timber::get_posts( $venue_query );
Timber::render( 'beesknees-participating-venues.twig', $context );
```

I'm trying to follow this [ACF forum thread](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/multiple-post-points-on-google-maps/) in order to loop through all venues and create a marker for each on a google map. Since I cannot do this on a twig template:

```
<?php
    $location = get_field('c_gmaps');
    $gtemp = explode ('|', $location);
    $coord = explode (',', $gtemp[1]);
    $lat = (float) $coord[0];
    $lng = (float) $coord[1];
?>

<div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $lat; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $lng; ?>">
```

I've tried writing a function in my page.php file :

```
function render_markers(&$location) {
    var_dump($location);
    $gtemp = explode (',',  implode($location));
    $coord = explode (',', implode($gtemp));
    echo    '<div class="marker" data-lat="' . $location[lat] .'" data-lng="'. $location[lng] .'">

    <p class="address">' . $gtemp[0] . '<a href="' . the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to '. the_title_attribute() .'">' . the_title() . '</a></p>       
      </div>';
}
```

and then use it in my twig template:

```
{% for item in venue %}
    {% set location = item.get_field('google_map')  %}
    {{ function('render_markers', 'location') }}
{% endfor %}
```

That generates the repeating error:

> Warning: Parameter 1 to render_markers() expected to be a reference, 
>   value given in
>   /app/public/wp-content/plugins/timber-library/lib/Twig.php on line 310
>   string(8) "location"  Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in
>   /app/public/wp-content/themes/my_theme/page.php on line 122 Warning:
>   Illegal string offset 'lat' in
>   /app/public/wp-content/themes/my_theme/page.php on line 124

I think I'm close but I'm not sure. I can't find specific enough examples in the Twig or Timber documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Quick Fix

This feels hacky, but this (might) be a quick solve

This line...

```
{{ function('render_markers', 'location') }}
```

... is merely sending the string "location" to the function. You want the Twig variable you just created. Try changing it to...

```
{{ function('render_markers', location) }}
```

#### Big Fix

This is the more "elegant solution"

```
<?php

class Venue extends Timber\Post {

    function coordinates() {
        $location = $this->get_field('c_gmaps');
        $gtemp = explode ('|', $location);
        $coord = explode (',', $gtemp[1]);
        return $coord;

    }

    function latitude() {
        $coord = this->coordinates();
        $lat = (float) $coord[0];
        return $lat;
    }

    function longitude() {
        $coord = this->coordinates();
        $lng = (float) $coord[1];
        return $lng;
    }

}


/* at the bottom of the PHP file you posted: */

$context['venue'] = Timber::get_posts( $venue_query, 'Venue' );
Timber::render( 'beesknees-participating-venues.twig', $context );
```

In your Twig file...

```
{% for item in venue %}
    <div class="marker" data-lat="{{ item.latitude }}" data-lng="{{ item.longitude }}">
    <p class="address">{{ item.latitude }}<a href="{{ item.link }}" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to {{ item.title | escape }}">{{ item.title }}</a></p>       
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jared. I'm working on the elegant solution, placing the class Venue code in my page.php file inside the theme. I added $ in front of `this->coordiantes()` and then hit save. The issue is that `$location = get_field('c_gmaps');` returns null. I've checked the  variable name in ACF and it's correct. Is the `get_field` function available here?
Thanks again.

Comment: I fixed that line to be `$this->get_field('c_gmaps');`

Comment: ... also if you find you need the `Venue` class in other places, move it to its own file ("Venue.php") and include it in your `functions.php` file (`require_once('Venue.php')`) so it can be used throughout the site

Comment: Thanks again @Jared. That worked!  It solved the problem of getting ACF data in usable form to loop through. Now the issue is getting field data in a usable form (the delimiter " | " is missing) but that is a separate issue. 
Gracias